# Promise does not resolve second time

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, es6-promise

I try to something general. When form submit first time it works fine, but second time it does not resolve. I use jquery.form.min.js. I think, the problem is form already submitted, but i can't figure it out. I also tried ajax post. Result is same.

```
const makeRequest = formName =>
new Promise((resolve) => {
  $(formName).ajaxForm({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //some code here
      resolve(response);
    }
  });
});


makeRequest('form')
    .then((res) => {
       //some code here
    });
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('product-confirmation') }}" class="needs-validation">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="product_name">Title:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" autocomplete="off" required>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="product_description">Description:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="product_description" name="product_description"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer justify-content-end">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="form">Update</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is `ajaxForm`, why doesn't it return a promise? Also don't forget to add an error handler to reject the promise!

Comment: There is no problem in the code you've shown that would cause this problem. It's either on the server side, in the `//some code here`, or elsewhere.

Comment: You need to give more info on when makeRequest function is invoked? From your code I assume that you click on a button which invokes makeRequest function and resolves the value obtained by submitting the form via ajaxForm method.

Comment: A promise can only be resolved once. Are you sure you are not storing the promise somewhere and trying to resolve it again, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I added more information. Ajax form is a jquery library. It sends form information to controller. I added reject part too. Result is same. No error, but second time does not resolve. I have also another function. It works. The difference is this function sends form information. Nothing more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Terry You are probably right. I think the same. Maybe due to the form submission, I did not find yet.